# selecting an attribute from XML in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, string

Okay, I have a table that has a column called `bdParameters`, datatype is `text`. The data stored in the `bdParameters` column is XML saved as text.

The data goes like this:

```
<root>
    <row statusID="ALL" subID="ALL" viewMaskFields="false" masID="219" 
         userID="13" prptyDate="08/19/2011" docID="21b15c9e-76a5-44ed-afbb-96b6df2cf881" 
         resmID="8806" leaID="6345" reshID="3560" doEmail="" emailFrom="" emailTo="" 
         emailMsg="penarands" emailSubject="" fieldList="1" fmtID="2" OptInCES="Yes" 
         SendVaiEmailCES="1" RPIPMCURL="blabla@blabla.com" />
    <Custom>
       <UpdateResidentLetter>
          <Row Status="NOTPRINTED" Notes="Created from bulk lettersinterface" />
       </UpdateResidentLetter>
    </Custom>
</root>
```

I want to be able to select only the attribute `emailMsg` from that xml.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml.value with the `@` symbol to get the attribute

```
declare @t table (col xml);
insert @t select '
<root><row statusID="ALL" subID="ALL" viewMaskFields="false" masID="219" 
userID="13" prptyDate="08/19/2011" docID="21b15c9e-76a5-44ed-afbb-96b6df2cf881" 
resmID="8806" leaID="6345" reshID="3560" doEmail="" emailFrom="" emailTo="" 
emailMsg="penarands" emailSubject="" fieldList="1" fmtID="2" OptInCES="Yes" 
SendVaiEmailCES="1" RPIPMCURL="lm-10-254-9-52.onesitedev.realpage.com" /><Custom>
<UpdateResidentLetter><Row Status="NOTPRINTED" Notes="Created from bulk letters
 interface" /></UpdateResidentLetter></Custom></root>';

select col.value('(/root/row/@emailMsg)[1]','varchar(max)') emailMsg
from @t

-- result
penarands
```